# Vehicle Identification Number File Creation

Tags: android, datatables, data-storage

I am planning on building an app which finds details of a particular manufacturers vehicle by entering the VIN number of the vehicle and then displaying the relevant details to the user.

I will store each letter and number along with their meanings and descriptions.

To store the above I have thought about a table in SQL and then accessing the rows and columns via JDBC. I have also thought about a switch statement. Bearing in mind the app would have to read each character. Example, the VIN starts with EF, E meaning Europe, F meaning France.

What would be the best and most efficient way or tool to store this information that would be easily accessible through the app?

I have tried searching the web for VIN tables, there are many tables available but hardly any details on the creation of these tables.

The application will be built in Android Studio.

Any feedback appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for starters being very organized is a must with this project, probably includes sorting the years of the cars, manufacturer, location, ect. Now would this be limited to cars? And can you elaborate on what you mean for a switch element?

Sorry I can't be more detailed I just need more information on the project. :)

Comment: It's going to be a simple app as it is my first app so it won't be anything special. When the app opens, it will basically have a field where the user can type a VIN number, click on a button and then see the identity of the car. What I need to do apart from developing the app, I need to make a file which has the relevant details. For instance if my user type a VIN starting with SC the app will know to return Europe and England. I basically want to make a reference point/file/table to which the app will connect to to find this info. Hope this was a better description....Thanks

Comment: Oh and the app will be limited to cars only yes.

Comment: About the switch, it was just an idea maybe I could have some cases in a switch statement saying if 1 then return this or if 2 return that and have the VIN data in there. Not sure if that's a solution though. I would prefer a seperate file so I am able to edit the data easier as needed in the future. Sorry for the repeating comments.

Comment: After some research, this particular app I see will require many things, so I'm going to look into it in a different manner. Thought it was easier but it seems to have many things to look at. I will end the post. Thank you for your time.